# Uncaught TypeError: color is undefined || MUI Button & CreateTheme Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, typeerror

I am trying to use MUI's createTheme and utilize the Button component. The theme is working for the entire application, however for some reason the  component is throwing this error when attempt to use it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: color is undefined
```

Here is my theme.js

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
  primary: {
    main: "#aa130f",
  },
  secondary: {
    light: "#726A6A",
    main: "#000000",
  },
  error: {
    main: "#D72A2A",
  },
  warning: {
    main: "#FC7B09",
  },
  info: {
    light: "CDCDCD",
    main: "#902020",    
  },
  success: {
    main: "#09FE00",
  },
  background: {
    default: "#342c2c",
  },
  divider: "#000000" ,
  text: "#000000",
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      label: {
        color: "#f1#f1#f1",
      }
    }
  }
    }
});
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./app/App";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { theme } from "./utils/theme/themes";
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
     </ThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is part of my component.
list.js

```
import {
  Box,
 Button
} from "@mui/material";

return(
      <Box sx={{display: "flex"}}>
       <NavBar />
       <Box sx={{
         marginTop: 5,
         display: "flex",
         justifyContent:"space-between"
       }}>
       <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Master List</Button>
         <Button>Test</Button>
         </Box>      
       </Box>
)
```

I have tried a few different solutions that I have seen on here but I have unable to figure out what is causing the issue. If I remove palette:{} from createTheme the theme colors are the default palette colors and the button component will work however, the app isn't the correct style. I tried overriding the Button in the createTheme and this still didn't work.

Comment: probably because you are setting the MuiButton label color to `"#f1#f1#f1"`

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Thanks for the response! I have tried to just completely remove the "MuiButton" label completely and use the "default" styling and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Also check the info light color, it's missing `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to determine that the issue was the way I had defined the "text" color within createTheme.

Original theme.js

```
  text: "#000000",
```

Working theme.js

```
  text: {
    primary: "#000000",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is setting the wrong value in the MuiButton color style, maybe should be like this.

```js
MuiButton: {
      label: {
        color: "#f1f1f1",
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also did try  this. I also removed the entire "MuiButton" theming component to so that its using the "default" theme however, I am still receiving the same error.